# IE browser opens even after specifying firefox using selenium testng

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, testng

I am using Eclipse IDE and using testNG framework.
I have specified firefox but the test runner opens in Firefox and test gets executed in IE.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Flipkart extends SeleneseTestNgHelper {

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup()
    {
           selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost" ,4444, "*firefox", "http://www.flipkart.com");
           selenium.start();
           selenium.windowMaximize();
    }

    @Test 
    public void testFlipkart() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("http://www.flipkart.com");
        verifyEquals(selenium.getTitle(), "Online Shopping India | Buy Books, Mobiles, Cameras, Laptops, Electronics, Accessories, Lifestyle Products | Flipkart.com");
        verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Featured:"));
    }

}
```

Has anyone faced the same problem. Please suggest what's wrong with code.

Comment: What is your selected choice in the Window->Web browser menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the eclipse default browser to firefox(sometimes it helps)
add firefox to class path. also take a look at the firefox version you are using this should be compatible with selenium

Comment: I changed eclipse default browser to Firefox and my Firefox version is 12.0 and it is compatible with Selenium too. But still I'm facing with the same problem.

Comment: try the older version of firefox, that should do it.

Comment: I changed to *googlechrome also.. Still the test gets executed in IE. An instance of Google Chrome opens but its of no use.

Comment: i use google chrome to run the tests and it runs perfectly. i use chrome version 19.0.1084.52 m, please cross check this. also have u added the browser to class path??

Answer (score 0):

Use `*chrome` instead of `*firefox`.

Also, check if the selenium server started.

Answer (score 0):

```
I was also getting same problem, Try out below  code for Solution this will help you

public static String browser="firefox";  //declare Browser this in the class heading.


@BeforeSuite

 public void setupBeforeSuite() throws Exception{
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,browser, "http://www.google.com");
selenium.start();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps ::

```
*STEP 1* : import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
         import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
         import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

*Step 2* : WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

*Step 3* : driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```